# Gradle doesn't really honor execution order

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have a Gradle build 3 tasks, first one should set type of deployment (test/staging/production), seconds just a helper to show current type. Third one implements actual deployment (not so important for this question, actually). Like this:

```
task toTest() {
    project.ext.set('deployType', 'test')
    println "Set deploy type: ${project.deployType}"
}
task showStatus() {
    mustRunAfter = ['toTest', 'toStage', 'toProd']
    println "Curr deploy type: ${project.deployType}"
}
task deploy(dependsOn: [toTest, showStatus]) {
   ...
}
```

The problem that Gradle says that it runs in following order: `toTest` -> `showStatus` -> `deploy`. But as I see from console it uses different order:

```
////....initial tasks
:buildSrc:build UP-TO-DATE
Curr deploy type: local

Set deploy type: test
:toTest UP-TO-DATE
////.......a lot of other tasks
:showStatus UP-TO-DATE
////... final deployment
```

I see two opposite things: order of execution is `toTest`->`showStatus`, but output first comes from `showStatus` and only then from `toTest`. How that's possible? What i'm doing wrong?

Gradle 2.2

PS Also, seems that `project.ext` is just ignored, or value is not visible from other tasks. But seems that it's a topic for another question.

Comment: shouldnt the prints there be in the `doLast`?

Comment: not sure what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code in the task definition is execute whenever this it is "read"  if you want to have actions done, when the task runs make "last".  (`<<` is shorthand for `doLast`) E.g.

```
task toTest() {
        project.ext.set('deployType', 'test')
}
toTest << {
        println "Set deploy type: ${project.deployType}"
}
task showStatus() {
        mustRunAfter = ['toTest']
}
showStatus << {
        println "Curr deploy type: ${project.deployType}"
}
task lerl(dependsOn: [toTest, showStatus]) {
        println "lerl"
}
```

Gives

```
lerl
:toTest
Set deploy type: test
:showStatus
Curr deploy type: test
:lerl
```